# Math questions for math game

Tags: games

I am building a math game, the Problem I am not a math teacher. :)

So I am trying to find the best way to create questions for different ages and different levels, I tried to google it but no luck.

In more details I want to know for each age what type of questions I should add what is the complexity and best way to move for next level for the kids. So its more math and education question.

Example that comes in mind: Age 5 should have addition between 0 and 10 and player can go to next level if he passes first 3 levels (30 question). etc....

Kindly if you know any article about this will be great

Comment: What is your math background? Why are you wanting to build a math game?

Comment: I am a programmer, I have good math background but not a teacher

Answer (score 8):

1. Go research it.  This is not suitable for small answer Q&A.  It's too big a topic--what topics to cover for each grade of math!
2. Go look at some of the existing products in this genre.  Buy a few, play them, read the Amazon reviews on their plus, minus, etc.  You do realize your game will not be the first creature of this species to walk the Earth, right?
3. Build some alphas and test them.  That is what you want to do first, anyways, right?

P.s.  You'd do a lot better by drilling down on one particular area, not looking at all ages.  And no, don't ask me, which one.  Go wallow around until you find one that looks interesting to you.

P.s.s. Although this board covers all math teaching in scope in theory, in practice, it has very few pre-college teachers, and those few are in high schools.  You need to look for other areas for input for lower level math teacher input.  There is sort of an ecosystem of teacher blogs for instance.  Or just talk to local teachers.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! Primary math standards vary by location, but you can see some examples from the US (I just googled "k12 math standards"):

https://www.michigan.gov/documents/mde/K-12_MI_Math_Standards_REV_470033_7_550413_7.pdf

https://education.ky.gov/curriculum/standards/kyacadstand/Documents/Kentucky_Academic_Standards_Mathematics.pdf

https://www.nd.gov/dpi/sites/www/files/documents/Academic%20Support/v3.Mathematics%20Standards%20Final%208.14.17.pdf

These documents are quite long. Khan Academy has a more succinct list of skills, and comes with some example auto-generated problems: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/k-8-grades

In terms of how to move students on from one level to the next, I suggest reading into Leitner Boxes: https://ncase.me/remember/ .